# how to setText in Search Functionality for ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

i make inputsearch in my listview and and i've make settext in the inputsearch when it open. i've set a word in the inputsearch field but the problem it can search by the word i've set. it must be type because in inputsearch field have filter the word that we type. may someone help me how i can set the text in inputsearch field without filter, when i open my listview , my listview will automatic just show the value from the word i set in inputsearch field. sorry for my bad english and thank you guys.

[image]

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                /**
                 * Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
                 **/
                 HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 user = db.getUserDetails();
                 inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                   inputSearch.setText(user.get("fname"),TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        semuatempat.this, data_map,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { tanya_nama, tanya_judul, tanya_komen,tanya_jawaban,tanya_waktu}, 
                        new int[] {R.id.nama, R.id.alamat, R.id.lat,R.id.lng,R.id.waktu});
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

        // selecting single ListView item
          ListView lv = getListView();


          inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)  {
                    // When user changed the Text
                   semuatempat.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                         
                }
            });
```

Comment: cudnt get man!....u mean u dont need filtering to happen when u type somthing??

Comment: i mean i dont need type .
i want the word that i set can automatic filter without i type because i've set the text bro.
thank you @ASP

Comment: onPostExecute is already in ui thread.

Comment: try notifying the list adapter after this line ::   semuatempat.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); adapter.notifyDatasetchanged();

Comment: try notifying like what bro? i'am not understand.
can you teach me? thank you @ASP

Comment: @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)  {
                    // When user changed the Text
                   semuatempat.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                }       //REplace your onTextChanged with this one  and check whether it works.

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is used to refresh the listview items.

Comment: nothing change bro, but thank you for your help.@ASP

Comment: ooo, thank you.
in this line, i've set the text show i don't must to type to input what i need but it dont work, u can see the screenshot i give. i've set "windy" in inputsearch but the result there's not only windy.
the filter work when i type, not when i set.  @ASP
inputSearch.setText(user.get("fname"),TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

Comment: That might solve your problem.